# Feign QueryMap usage with POJO

Tags: kotlin, netflix-feign, feign

I've found in [FEIGN-README](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#dynamic-query-parameters) that I can do stuff like:

```
interface MarketDataRestClient {
    @RequestLine("GET /api/v1/depth")
    fun getOrderBook(@QueryMap orderBookQuery: OrderBookQuery) : OrderBook
}
```

OrderBookQuery:

```
data class OrderBookQuery(val symbol: String, val limit: Int? = 100)
```

And Feign should generate query params: `/api/v1/depth?symbol={symbol}&limit={limit}`

Unfortunately all I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueryMap parameter must be a Map: class OrderBookQuery
at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:128)
at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:126)
at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidatateMetadata(Contract.java:64)
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:146)
at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:53)
at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:198)
at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:194)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature will be available in `9.7`.  The current published version, as of the writing of this answer, is `9.6`.  If you do not want to wait, please clone the repository and run build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a QueryMapEncoder,like：

```
return Feign
        .builder()
        .client(new OkHttpClient())
        .logger(new Logger.ErrorLogger()).logLevel(Logger.Level.BASIC)
        .queryMapEncoder(new BeanQueryMapEncoder())
        .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
        .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
```

Comment: Please add more explanation that why this code snippet should work.
I am sharing a possible explanation here. 
```/**
 * the query map will be generated using java beans accessible getter property as the query parameter

 * names.
 
 * eg: "/uri?name={name}&number={number}"

 * order of included query parameters is not guaranteed, and as usual, if any value is null, it will be

 * left out
 */```